# Sum of a column on condition from different date columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hi i have a dataframe as :

```
order_number   created_at     invoiced_at   shipped_at  quantity
UT637RR        2020-01-04     2020-01-06    2020-01-08  45
JYWEDER        2020-03-04     2020-03-04    2020-03-11  15
KFUV89R        2020-02-07     2020-02-13    2020-02-18  23
USKUV8R        2020-01-14     2020-01-16    2020-01-18  22
WUYT8RR        2020-02-13     2020-01-23    2020-01-30  12
```

I want to sum how much quantity was created, how much quantity was invoiced, how much quantity was shipped yesterday.

I tried this method but I'm not getting the desired result

```
df <- df %>% 
  select(processed_quantity,i_d,s_d,c_d) %>% 
  group_by(i_d,s_d,c_d) %>%
  summarise(id = sum(processed_quantity),sd = sum(processed_quantity),cd = sum(processed_quantity))
```

Comment: what do you mean by yesterday?

Comment: The code should automatically give the sum for Sys.Date() -1 , If im running it today it should give for yesterday

Comment: is it just yesterday's data you need or you need sum **till** yesterday?

Comment: only yesterday's

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  gather(type,date,-order_number,-quantity) %>%
  group_by(type,date) %>%
  summarise(quantity = sum(quantity) %>%
  filter(date == //yesterday) # here you should put the actual date you are looking for
```

This solution first creates a data frame that has one column for date type (created, shipped, invoiced) and one column for the actual date.

Then we use `group_by()` to aggregate the quantity for each date and type.

Comment: When you use ```gather``` you pivot all columns not excluded with ```-var``` into only two columns a "key" and a "value". In our case, I called the key ```type``` and it can be created_at,invoiced_at or shipped_at. The value in our case is "date" and it shows the relevant date. So before gather you had one row per date with five columns and after gather you have three rows per date with only 2 columns (order_number and quantity).

Comment: its giving this error Error in gather(., i_d, s_d, c_d, date, -order_number, -processed_quantity) : 
  could not find function "gather"

Comment: i used this code df <- df %>%
  gather(i_d,s_d,c_d,date,-order_number,-processed_quantity) %>% 
  group_by(i_d,s_d,c_d,date) %>%  
  summarise(quantity = sum(processed_quantity)) %>%
  filter(date == Sys.Date()-1)

Comment: @AnshulGupta did you include ```library(dplyr)``` and do you actually have this library installed?

Comment: @AnshulGupta, The function `gather()` is in the tidyr package.